# boto3 rds modify_db_snapshot_attribute not doing anything

Tags: python, amazon-rds, boto3

I want to set the restore attribute on rds snapshots so I can access them from another account, here is the code I've got to achieve that:

```
    params = dict(DBSnapshotIdentifier=snapshot_identifier,
                  AttributeName=attribute_name)
    if remove:
        params['ValuesToRemove'] = [str(value)]
    else:
        params['ValuesToAdd'] = [str(value)]
    response = self.client.modify_db_snapshot_attribute(**params)
```

When I run that code, checking attributes before and after, as well as response value:

```
DBSnapshotAttributesResult {u'DBSnapshotIdentifier': 'test-api-db-restore01-snapshot-2016-04-01', u'DBSnapshotAttributes': [{u'AttributeName': 'restore', u'AttributeValues': []}]}
```

{u'DBSnapshotAttributesResult': {u'DBSnapshotIdentifier': 'test-api-db-restore01-snapshot-2016-04-01', u'DBSnapshotAttributes': [{u'AttributeName': 'restore', u'AttributeValues': []}]}

```
DBSnapshotAttributesResult {u'DBSnapshotIdentifier': 'test-api-db-restore01-snapshot-2016-04-01', u'DBSnapshotAttributes': [{u'AttributeName': 'restore', u'AttributeValues': []}]}
```

I am not getting any errors - just the same state afterward that I had before.  What's going on?  How do I get this to work?

Comment: How about showing values of params before execute client.modify_db_snapshot_attribute()?

Comment: params: {'ValuesToAdd': ['ACCOUNT_ID'], 'DBSnapshotIdentifier': 'test-api-db-restore01-snapshot-2016-04-01', 'AttributeName': 'restore'}

Comment: Please check whether the particular ACCOUNT_ID are given the rights of "RestoreDBInstanceFromDBSnapshot".

Comment: having "all" in "ValuesToAdd" worked

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ShareSnapshot.html 
Please try the sharing snapshot option using AWS console.  Make sure the Account_id is valid AWS ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in an update to botocore [issue on github](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/649)